# Alignment of ListView items in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin

I have two informations on each item: place name and distance, I would like to list them side by side as a unique item but distance should  to stay on the right and place name on the left. I did it using 2 listviews inside a horizontal Stack layout and seemed ok but when user selects some item the scroll appears and mess the look and the user is abble to scroll just places or distances, I cant allow that. Can anyone give me a suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You should use two labels instead of two list views. One label is for placename and another is for distance and put them in a StackLayout with Horizontal Orientation. Right and Left can be achieved by setting appropriate values to HorizontalOptions on each label.

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <Label Text="Place Name" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
    <Label Text="Distance" HorizontalOptions="End" />
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: i didn't said that I have about 60 rows of data,  listview isn't more apropriated in this case?

Comment: There is anyway to put this labels as items of the listview?

Comment: Yes, you should create a [ListView with a custom ViewCell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-cell-appearance#custom-cells)